# How to append a childnode to a specific position

Tags: javascript, dom, parent-child

How can I append a childNode to a specific position in javascript?

I want to add a childNode to the 3rd position in a div. There are other nodes behind it that need to move backwards (3 becomes 4 etc.)

Comment: [insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.insertBefore)

Answer (score 187, accepted):

You can use [**`.insertBefore()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.insertBefore):

```
parentElement.insertBefore(newElement, parentElement.childNodes[2]);
```

Comment: Can you explain why you've chosen to go `parentElement.children` rather than `parentElement.childNodes`?  The former lists only children which are `Element`s, thus ignoring nodes which are `Text`s, for example... Wouldn't it be better to assume that the child nodes may include all types of nodes???

Comment: @mikerodent For example, when you work with list items `<li>` in an ordered list `<ol>`, you wouldn't want to have the white space indentation to count as a child (assuming the HTML document is pretty).

Comment: Using childNodes over children is the right way to go here.

Answer (score 57):

For this you have 3 options .insertBefore(), .insertAdjacentElement() or .insertAdjacentHtml()

---

[**`.insertBefore()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore)

```
var insertedElement = parentElement.insertBefore(newElement, referenceElement);
```

in your case you could do as on [Felix Kling answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5882802/1733169)

```
var insertedElement = parentElement.insertBefore(newElement, parentElement.children[2]);
```

---

[**`.insertAdjacentElement()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536451(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
referenceElement.insertAdjacentElement (where, newElement);
```

in your case it would be

```
parentElement.children[1].insertAdjacentElement("afterEnd", newElement);
```

---

[**`.insertAdjacentHTML()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.insertAdjacentHTML)

```
referenceElement.insertAdjacentElement (where, newElementHTML);
```

in your case it would be

```
parentElement.children[1].insertAdjacentElement("afterEnd", "<td>newElementHTML</td>");
```

Answer (score 21):

### To insert a child node at a specific index

Simplified,

```
Element.prototype.insertChildAtIndex = function(child, index) {
  if (!index) index = 0
  if (index >= this.children.length) {
    this.appendChild(child)
  } else {
    this.insertBefore(child, this.children[index])
  }
}
```

Then,

```
var child = document.createElement('div')
var parent = document.body
parent.insertChildAtIndex(child, 2)
```

Tada!

*Be aware of when extending natives [could be troublesome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice)*

Comment: Why give a warning instead of just writing a generic function that can be called with the parent node?

Comment: Was probably writing mostly vanilla js with little to no dependencies at the time, which makes extensions nice. With the bundlers and module systems we have today, a utility package exposing such a function would probably be preferable.

Comment: [“(If second argument) null, it will be inserted at the end.”](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_insertbefore.asp), thus, a `this.insertBefore(child, this.children[index]) || null` could simplify this?