# Position an element in certain place in DOM JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have this code which creates an element but the problem i am facing is it appends it at the very bottom of the page, in order for this to work i need it to be positioned in a certain place in the DOM how can i do this ?

```
var x  = document.getElementById('options_10528_1');
var pos = document.getElementById('options-10528-list');
x.onclick = function(){
var elem = document.createElement('div');
elem.setAttribute("class","uk-warning");
elem.innerHTML = "Unfortunately, we cannot supply this medicine. Please  consult your GP.";
document.body.appendChild(elem);
}
```

Comment: You must know the container to append element in..

Comment: I know what it's contained in so do i just append it to that ye ?

Comment: To position added element as child check this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882768/how-to-append-a-childnode-to-a-specific-position

Answer (score 0):

```
afterWhichNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, afterWhichNode.nextSibling);
```

This code will insert a node after the `afterwichNode`, thats using vanilla javascript, if you are using jquery, just use `.after()`

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are appending the element in the body tag, it will always goes at bottom. So if you want to append the element in a specific position, you have to append it in that container. let say you want to append it in "pos", you can do this:

```
pos.appendChild(elem);
```

Comment: Thank you it works, i did this before but i still kept the document in it so it was document.pos.appendChild.