# Add rows in HTML table with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to write `<td>` tags with JavaSctipt in my HTML code.
I'm building a `<table>` in the main code and I'd like to continue it with a `<script>`, adding rows in the division.

```
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>First</td>
    </tr>
    <div id="searchOutput"></div>
    <tr>
      <td>Last</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <script>
  document.getElementById("searchOutput").innerHTML = "<tr><td>Middle<td><tr>";
  </script>
</body>
```

The problem is that the `<script>` creates another table in a strange way.

[image: Chrome result]
[image: Chrome result]

Is there a way to add rows without writing all code (including `<table>` tags) in the `<script>`?

Comment: `table` children should  not be `div`s. Try selecting the `table` and appending a `tr` to it, or selecting an existing `tr` and putting `td`s/text into it

Comment: I already tried to insert the table data in various tag like `<p>` or `<h1>` and the problem was already there. I also tried to put a `<td>` in a `<tr>` but the result was always the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For insert new row in the table, you can use Table `insertRow()` and `insertCell()` Methods. The `insertRow()` methods creates an empty `<tr>` element and adds it to a table. The `insertCell()` method inserts a cell into the current row.

See the code below:

```js
function addRows() {
  var table = document.getElementById( 'myTable' ),
      row = table.insertRow(0),
      cell1 = row.insertCell(0),
      cell2 = row.insertCell(1);

  cell1.innerHTML = 'Cell 1';
  cell2.innerHTML = 'Cell 2';
}
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%
}
td {
  border: 1px solid #999
}
```

```html
<p>
  <button onclick="addRows()">Add a new row</button>
</p>
<table id="myTable"></table>
```

Answer (score 1):

CertainPerformance is correct; divs should not be direct children of tables. You might find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882768/how-to-append-a-childnode-to-a-specific-position) useful. You have the right idea, if only you could actually replace the HTML of the div as opposed to simply filling it in. So, you could set the ID of the Last tr to searchOutput. Then, something like

```
var newRow = document.createElement("tr");
var oldRow = document.getElementById("searchOutput");
newRow.innerHTML = "<tr><td>Middle</td></tr>";
document.getElementByTagName("table").insertBefore(row, oldRow);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the example from w3cschools.com  https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_table_insertrow

Comment: While this may technically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.