# GliderJS how to add item at a specific index in the carousel?

Tags: javascript, carousel

I am using gliderJS to create a carousel and I need to dynamically add and remove items from and to it.

I managed to get it working with the `.addItem` and `.removeItem()` methods, and while the removeItem supports removing from specific index, I dont see any way in the documentation to addItem at a specific index, does anyone know if that is possible?

This is the code so far about adding:

```
const elementHTML = "somehtml";
const element = document.createElement("div");
element.innerHTML = elementHTML;

glider.addItem(element);
```

And that adds it at the end of the carousel, I want to add it at a specific index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no exposed api to specifically do this. However, you can change the contents of the glider and call `refresh`, which is indeed exactly what the `addItem` method does:

```js
  gliderPrototype.addItem = function (ele) {
    var _ = this

    _.track.appendChild(ele)
    _.refresh(true)
    _.emit('add')
  }
```

So in theory, you should be able to [add a child to a specific index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882768/how-to-append-a-childnode-to-a-specific-position) in the track and call refresh, sorta like this:

```js
const glider = new Glider(document.querySelector('.glider'), {
  slidesToShow: 5,
  slidesToScroll: 5,
  draggable: true
})



function insertBeforeIndex (element, index) {
  glider.track.insertBefore(element, glider.track.children[index])
  glider.refresh()
}

const newElement = document.createElement("div")
newElement.innerHTML = "<em>new item</em>"

insertBeforeIndex(newElement, 2) // inserts it in 3rd place
```

```css
.box {
  border: 2px solid lightblue;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/glider-js@1/glider.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/glider-js@1/glider.min.js"></script>

<div class="glider-contain">
  <div class="glider">
    <div class="box"> 1 </div>
    <div class="box"> 2 </div>
    <div class="box"> 3 </div>
    <div class="box"> 4 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```