# How to Include Javascript inside javascript properly?

Tags: javascript, html, document.write

I am forced to put code in place where which when inserted, it applies to thousands of web pages.

I would like to only have a script work when a URL contains: "/pN2toKYZ/checkout" :

Here is what I am trying, i've also tried escaping bthe starting'<' but it did not work

```
<script>
if (window.location.href.indexOf('/pN2toKYZ/checkout') != -1) {
   document.write("<script>
  gtag('event', 'conversion', {'send_to': 'AW-834461893/ixLXCK-Wm6kDEMXB840D'});
 <\/script>
")
}
</script>
```

Comment: If the command in your script is to run depending on the URL part of the loaded page, why do you not just put that command in your conditional block: ` if(...whatever) {gtag('event', 'conversion',...}` this would have the exactly the same computation effect of you adding a new script containing it. If I've missed something, you might want to clarify your question so we can help. If you really need to add a script to the loaded page I can explain if I know what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

The version shown in your question has line breaks, which are not allowed in strings. You might have put them in for presentation here but make sure they are not in your actual code.

If you must use `document.write` there's no need to escape anything in your quotted string argument of `document.write` (if it contained the same quote marks as you use to quote it, they would need to be escaped but tags etc. are fine).

Although I can't see why the command specified in the 'created' script inside your your conditional cannot simply be placed directly in your conditional (without needing to write a new script to the page), if I had to add a script created by a script, I would create a new script element, add innerText to it specifying the required commands, and then append the the script element to the document.

If your added script needs to be placed at a specific part of the page (rather than appended as the last child of the body as in my example) you can learn more here: [How to append a childnode to a specific position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882768/how-to-append-a-childnode-to-a-specific-position)

The following example has a single script which creates a new script with a single command to change the page background color. CSS has been used to show the actual scripts in the rendered html (for presentation only, irrelevant to function). You will see that the created script is added to the page and executed.

```js
let newScript = document.createElement('script');

newScript.innerText = "document.body.style='background: red';";

document.body.appendChild(newScript);
```

```css
body {
background: blue;
}

/*make scripts visible in html*/
script {
display: inline-block; 
border: 1px solid black; 
padding: 10px; 
white-space: pre-wrap;
font-family: monospace;
color: #00ff00;
background: #005500;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<h1> page with a single script</h1>
<p>The background color of the page is set to BLUE in the accompanying style sheet</p>
<p>This page has a single script tag included in its html. The script creates a new script element, adds a command to it, and appends the script to the page</p>
<p>the script added by js then changes the page background to red</p>
<p>both scripts are shown below in the rendered html (because the accompanying styles make them visible) but only the first one is written as a script in the original html</p>
```